# SQL to combine (de-duplicate) Table A based on Table B data?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

How do I write the SQL (SQLite3, postgres, or MySQL) to
combine (de-duplicate) Table A based on Table B data?

Given People (table: contacts) that have Phone Numbers (table: phones),
I want to use phone numbers to remove duplicate contacts.

In this example there the company is there for clarification, the
real data may not have the same company listed even though the
person is the same based on phone number.

Note, in this example, there are two distinct Betty's, but the
two Charles are the same person and should be combined.

Also, Ashok and Dale have a common phone number because they
work for the same company, but are not the same person.

```
Table: contacts
===============
id      name      company
1       Ashok     Alpha Co.
2       Betty     Beta Inc.
3       Charles   Cain LLC.          <---|
4       Betty     Delta Corp.            |-- same person
5       Charles   Cain LLC.          <---|
6       Dale      Alpha Co.

Table: phones
============
id      phone_number    contact_id
1       (111) 123-1111  1
2       (111) 123-2222  1
3       (111) 123-3333  1
4       (111) 123-4444  1
5       (222) 456-1111  2
6       (222) 456-2222  2
7       (333) 789-1111  3
8       (333) 789-2222  3
9       (333) 789-3333  3
10      (333) 789-4444  3
11      (444) 456-7777  4
12      (444) 456-8888  4
13      (555) 789-5555  5
14      (333) 789-2222  5
15      (111) 123-3333  6
```

Joining the tables gives:

```
SELECT      c.id, c.name, c.company, p.phone_number, p.contact_id
FROM        contacts as c
INNER JOIN  phones as p
ON          c.id = p.contact_id

c.id    c.name      c.company       p.phone         p.contact_id
1       Ashok       Alpha Co.       (111) 123-1111  1
1       Ashok       Alpha Co.       (111) 123-2222  1
1       Ashok       Alpha Co.       (111) 123-3333  1
1       Ashok       Alpha Co.       (111) 123-4444  1
2       Betty       Beta Inc.       (222) 456-1111  2
2       Betty       Beta Inc.       (222) 456-2222  2
3       Charles     Cain LLC.       (333) 789-1111  3
3       Charles     Cain LLC.       (333) 789-2222  3
3       Charles     Cain LLC.       (333) 789-3333  3
3       Charles     Cain LLC.       (333) 789-4444  3
4       Betty       Delta Corp.     (444) 456-7777  4
4       Betty       Delta Corp.     (444) 456-8888  4
5       Charles     Cain LLC.       (555) 789-5555  5
5       Charles     Cain LLC.       (333) 789-2222  5
6       Dale        Alpha Co.       (111) 123-3333  6
```

So what I am thinking is that I would want to loop through all
of the distint phone numbers, get all of the contacts for each
of those numbers, check to see if the names are the same, if
they are remove the duplicate contact and change the contact_ids
on the phone numbers.

so the result would look like:

```
Table: contacts
===============
id      name      company
1       Ashok     Alpha Co.
2       Betty     Beta Inc.
3       Charles   Cain LLC.
4       Betty     Delta Corp.       <-- Note the duplicate Charles (5) is removed
6       Dale      Alpha Co.

Table: phones
============
id      phone_number    contact_id
1       (111) 123-1111  1
2       (111) 123-2222  1
3       (111) 123-3333  1
4       (111) 123-4444  1
5       (222) 456-1111  2
6       (222) 456-2222  2
7       (333) 789-1111  3
8       (333) 789-2222  3
9       (333) 789-3333  3
10      (333) 789-4444  3
11      (444) 456-7777  4
12      (444) 456-8888  4
13      (555) 789-5555  3         <-- Note the contact_id is updated
15      (111) 123-3333  6         <-- Note the duplicate phone number (14) is removed
```

or

```
c.id    c.name      c.company       p.phone         p.contact_id
1       Ashok       Alpha Co.       (111) 123-1111  1
1       Ashok       Alpha Co.       (111) 123-2222  1
1       Ashok       Alpha Co.       (111) 123-3333  1
1       Ashok       Alpha Co.       (111) 123-4444  1
2       Betty       Beta Inc.       (222) 456-1111  2
2       Betty       Beta Inc.       (222) 456-2222  2
3       Charles     Cain LLC.       (333) 789-1111  3
3       Charles     Cain LLC.       (333) 789-2222  3
3       Charles     Cain LLC.       (333) 789-3333  3
3       Charles     Cain LLC.       (333) 789-4444  3
4       Betty       Delta Corp.     (444) 456-7777  4
4       Betty       Delta Corp.     (444) 456-8888  4
3       Charles     Cain LLC.       (555) 789-5555  3
6       Dale        Alpha Co.       (111) 123-3333  6
```

Answer (score 1):

The following makes an assumption that your problem is as simple as you say it is.  In other words, it is only looking for pairs of contacts that are the same, and not traversing a graph that could be much more complicated.

If you are saying that any two contacts with the same phone number (no matter how many they have) and the same name are the same, then you can find them using:

```
with cp as (
      select c.*, p.phone_number
      from contacts c join
           phones p
           on c.id = p.contact_id
     )
select distinct cp.id as id1, cp2.id as id2
from cp join
     cp cp2
     on cp.phone_number = cp2.phone_number and cp.name = cp2.name and
        cp.id <> cp2.id;
```

Presumably, you want to keep the first contact.  So, let's use aggregation instead.  In this

```
select min(cp.id) as id1, cp2.id as id2
from cp join
     cp cp2
     on cp.phone_number = cp2.phone_number and cp.name = cp2.name and
         cp.id < cp2.id
group by cp2.id;
```

This produces pairs of contact ids.  We want to keep the first and delete the second.

Now, if we make the assumption that duplicates are only one deep, then we can incorporate this into a `delete`:

```
with cp as (
      select c.*, p.phone_number
      from contacts c join
           phones p
           on c.id = p.contact_id
     )
delete from contacts
    where id in (select cp2.id
                 from cp join
                      cp cp2
                      on cp.phone_number = cp2.phone_number and cp.name = cp2.name and
                         cp.id < cp2.id
                );
```

(The `group by` is actually unnecessary for the `in`.).

Note:  This does not work in MySQL, where the equivalent logic would need to be expressed using `JOIN` and CTEs are not supported.

Comment: How would this be different if there were duplicate contacts that appear more than twice?

Comment: @MERM . . . It depends on how they are represented in the telephone numbers.

Comment: In the same way, say to our original data we add contact: 7 Charles Cain Co.   and  phone  16    (333) 789-2222    7

Comment: The overlap of telephone numbers:  Craig could have T1, T2; then T2, T3; then T3, T4.  Is the first Craig the same as the last one?  This is a graph walking problem.  But it doesn't arise if there are at most two duplicates.

Comment: In the real data there is a properties table.  When the data was entered for each property, multiple contacts were added each with one or more phone numbers.  We want to remove duplicates (normalize our data) such that if any two or more contacts have the same name and at least one matching phone number, then they are considered the same person and we want to remove all but one instance of this person and assign all unique phone numbers to that person.

Comment: I just noticed, your solution removed the duplicate contacts, but doesn't reassign the orphaned phone numbers to the remaining contact.  How can I do that?

Comment: Gordon, I am up-voting your answer because it got me going on the solution, however it didn't solve the issues of the orphaned phone records, and deleting the duplicate contacts.  Ultimately, I had to do a bunch of queries and use perl to apply the logic.  It would've been cleaner all in SQL...

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is in three steps:

1. do a query that identifies duplicate records, picks ony redundant ones and save them into temporary table
2. delete contacts which are in this temp-table
3. delete phones which are in this temp-table

The first step could be done using this query (demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a20149/6)

```
-- CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS
SELECT p.id as id_phone,
       p.phone_number,
       p.contact_id,
       c.id as id_contact,
       c.name,
       c.company
FROM phones p
JOIN contacts c
ON p.contact_id = c.id
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 'Anythng' 
  FROM phones p1
  JOIN contacts c1
  ON p1.contact_id = c1.id
  WHERE p1.phone_number = p.phone_number
    AND c1.name = c.name
    AND c.id < c1.id 
);
```

---

```
| id_phone |   phone_number | contact_id | id_contact |    name |   company |
|----------|----------------|------------|------------|---------|-----------|
|        8 | (333) 789-2222 |          3 |          3 | Charles | Cain LLC. |
```

and then steps 2 and 3:

```
DELETE contacts WHERE ID IN (SELECT id_contact FROM temp_table);
DELETE phones WHERE ID IN (SELECT id_phone FROM temp_table);
```

Comment: This seems to work, except now all of the phone numbers that pointed to contact 3 would point to a non-existent contact.  How do I change all of these to contact 5?